# Self Study Question: How to show that Ordinary Least Squares estimator $\hat{\beta}$ can be written another way

Tags: least-squares, econometrics

Let $x_t$ be a $1$ x $(k+1)$ vector of explanatory variables for observation $t$. Show that the OLS estimator $\hat{\beta}$ can be written as:
$$ \hat{\beta} = \left(\sum_{t=1}^n x_t'x_t\right)^{-1}\left(\sum_{t=1}^n x_t'y_t\right)$$

I have no idea where to start with this, could someone provide a hint?

Comment: Typo? The OLS estimate is $(X^T X)^{-1} X^T Y$.

Comment: it's a rather big typo

Comment: @user365239 yes! sorry there was a typo, i fixed it

Comment: @user319635 what is OLS?

Comment: @Ben is it enough to show that if you expand these sums you get $(X^{T}X)^{−1}(X^{T}Y)$ ?

Comment: It depends on what you know about OLS. Do you know, or are willing to use, that the OLS estimator with design matrix $X$ and response vector $Y$ is $(X^TX)^{-1}X^T Y?$

Comment: @Ben yes we are currently learning the linear regression model in matrix form so we recently learned that $\hat{\beta} = (X^{T}X)^{−1}(X^{T}Y)$

Comment: Ah, okay, great! In that case, it may be fruitful to write down what the design matrix $X$ in terms of our problem at hand and evaluate $X^T X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming OLS stands for Ordinary Least Squares. You want to find

$$\hat \beta = \arg \min_\beta \sum_{t=1}^n (y_t - x_t\beta)^2 = \arg \min_\beta S(\beta,y,x),$$

I'm using $S(\beta,y,x)$ as a notation for the sum of squares function.

The hint it to use the fact that $S(\beta,y,x)$ is a convex function in $\beta$ for a fixed $y$ and $x$. This means that there is a unique minimum at $$\frac{\partial S(\beta,y,x)}{\partial \beta} = 0.$$

If you solve this equation you'll get your result.

Edit: Just for a more complete answer,

$$ \frac{\partial S(\beta,y,x)}{\partial \beta} =  \sum_{t=1}^n 2x_t'(y_t - x_t\beta) = 0$$

$$\sum_{t=1}^n x_t'y_t = \sum_{t=1}^nx_t'x_t\hat \beta $$
$$\left(\sum_{t=1}^nx_t'x_t\right)^{-1}\sum_{t=1}^n x_t'y_t = \hat \beta $$